# knockout validation errors for observables inside array objects

Tags: validation, knockout-2.0

I'm using the Validation library [Knockout Validation][1] with Knockout 2.  Although the UI displays validation error correctly for observable properties inside the array of objects.  The ko.validation.group function does not track these errors.  Looking at the source I see it only examines the observability of the array object itself and not internal observable properties.

I have an array of these

```
function Game(bowlerId, name, g1, g2, g3, g4) {
    this.BowlerId = bowlerId;
    this.Name = name;
    this.Game1 = ko.observable(g1).extend({ required: true, min:1, max:300  });
    this.Game2 = ko.observable(g2).extend({ required: true, min: 1, max: 300 });
    this.Game3 = ko.observable(g3).extend({ required: true, min: 1, max: 300 });
    this.Game4 = ko.observable(g4).extend({ required: true, min: 1, max: 300 });

}
```

which I use like:

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel.Games);
```

or like

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);
```

In either case the individual properties (Game1, Game2, etc), above are not tracked in the erros returned by the group function.   Validation errors do appear in the UI though.  Currently I have to query the DOM to see if the user has raised a validation error.  Is there some way I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel.Games, { deep: true });
```

Comment: I gave up on knockout because of this issue and will NEVER again use a framework that has core dependencies on other libraries (no support).  Validation is so critical it must be part of AND supported by the base framework.  I'm a very happy AngularJS user now.   thanks for the effort.